# Talk before quitting job

Tags: quitting

Next week I'll have a talk to my manager, saying that I intend to quit my job due to various reasons ('politics', not able to get a fair, interesting task, which has severe impact on my (technical) skills as a developer - although I've tried to search for compromises for almost a year now).

In my absence I was assigned to a special 'political' dev-project, which now is the 'smoking' gun for me for leaving the company if I get not unassigned. To be clear, this is just the tip of the iceberg and not the only reason for quitting.

Is it tactful to say that I leave the company if I get not unassigned of this project and if we find not a compromise that I get also the chance to get a fair task, evolving my career and skills in the midterm ?

Or should I just say I'm quitting and again give an overview about the reasons and just see if he / the organisation is more willing to search a compromise this time?

I have no intention of any confrontation, I just want to make sure the manager / company understands the reasons for my decision.

Comment: Also, [Is it unprofessional to fully speak your mind on job satisfaction with your boss or manager?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/17480/is-it-unprofessional-to-fully-speak-your-mind-on-job-satisfaction-with-your-boss) as well as [How much should I say in an exit interview?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/14921/how-much-should-i-say-in-an-exit-interview)

Comment: Your managers job is to assign work, not yours. If you said that to me I would make sure you knew not to let the door hit you on the way out. If you don't want to do what you were hired to do, just leave IMO.

Answer (score 13):

> Is it tactful to say that I leave the company if I get not unassigned
>   of this project?

No it is not tactful to issue an ultimatum to your employer about your assigned tasks.

It is reasonable to have a discussion about your career and skills development with your supervisor.  But as soon as you start throwing ultimatums around it stops being a reasonable discussion.

Comment: I had  these discussions several times, with no interest from the other side. So your recommendation would be to just quit then ?

Comment: @Hawk66 - If the only options are ultimatum or just quit... yes just quit

Comment: @Hawk66 A reasonable discussion might be a third option....

Comment: Most unreasonable ultimatums result in you "quitting" in a manner of speaking too...

Comment: @MisterPositive as stated I had these discussions. The supervisor / part of the management partly agrees but they do not change their behavior - not a bit.

Comment: @Hawk66 Did you have 3 reasonable discussions?  Big difference.

Comment: @MisterPositive yes, I had. They were reasonable and done in a 'friendly' atmosphere. But the outcome was zero

Comment: @hawk66 - Try asking what they want to see from you to make your goals happen.  If all you do is demand its not really a negotiation or discussion its just a demand.

Comment: @IDrinkandIKnowThings I've taken unpopular tasks for over a year now. The main reason for not changing their behavior is company politics. To change things in that environment costs energy for them. I have by no means unreasonable demands and I've always made clear that I accept a compromise

Comment: @Hawk66 - So if I understand you right you gave your *reasonable demands* in a *friendly discussion* of what you expect your company to do for their junior employee and they have not fallen all over themselves to make your life better?

Comment: @IDrinkandIKnowThings I'm not a junior developer, nor would I be the first in the team qutting for the same reasons.

Comment: @Hawk66 - I didnt say junior developer, I said junior employee.  I say junior employee because you have only 1 year at the job, and are not in a  leadership role.  Even if you are their most skilled developer you are still a junior employee at the company.  So unless youa re going to tell me that 90% of the employees at the company have less than 6 months at the company yes you are a junior employee

Comment: @IDrinkandIKnowThings This is a misunderstanding. I work for the company for over a decade. I had other tasks/projects in the past

Comment: @hawk66 - I suggest you ask the question.  I am a long time employee who has recently been relegated to handling the most undesirable tasks.  How can effectively approach management about getting me desirable tasks.  and in the question define what undesirable and desireable mean in broad strokes.