# How soon should I communicate to my employer I am looking into pursuing a doctorate?

Tags: career-development, career-switch, continuing-education

I'm working as a software developer in a company doing product R&D consulting. I've been here for 10 months and it's my first full-time job after graduating with a Masters last year. For various reasons, I have started to consider pursuing a PhD, starting in the Autumn of next year.

I am pretty sure I want to communicate this desire to my employer for several reasons:

- Honesty - they are investing in me in the form of training and
  knowing I might leave might alter their desire to do so;
- Letters of recommendation - I will *definitely* want my employer's assistance in getting into a desired programme, probably in a form of a letter of recommendation. I am on very good terms with my manager and technical lead so in general I don't think there would be any problems with asking them for that;
- "Returnability" - because of the *R* in the *R&D* of my company (and because plainly my company a great place to work), I can see being seriously interested in coming back here in a different role after being done with my PhD (or if I change my mind during it).Thus I want to keep friendly relations with the company and not just pull off a surprise quit on them.

What I'm not sure about is *when* would be a good time to communicate this potential plan of mine to the employer. On one hand keeping this thought to myself makes me feel dishonest, on the other hand I'm concerned that once I make my intention clear, even if it's not certain, my career will stop (no more training, no more interesting projects etc.).

So hence the question: When should I communicate this thought of mine and should I be mindful of anything I haven't considered yet when I do it?

Comment: Right now it is a potential plan.  Tell them after you get accepted and have decided for sure.

Comment: @Paparazzi I do need their assistance in order to get accepted though. I won't be able to get three letters from my University and I'm pretty sure the one I get from my TA would be glowing (if it's anything like my review feedback)

Comment: Then you statement "keeping this thought to myself makes me feel dishonest" does not make sense.

Comment: Could you still work there while attending your PhD program?

Comment: Why on earth do you need a LOR from people outside academia? Those won't count for anything if your university requires them. And frankly you should be more concerned about losing your job than your career. What country are you in?

Comment: I agree with @JasonJ. Would you consider going back to school part time while you continue to work? Many companies have programs that would help subsidize education costs.

Comment: I think your desire for a letter of recommendation makes your question distinct, but take a look at this question as well: [Is it naive to tell my current employer that I'll be leaving, months in advance?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6840/is-it-naive-to-tell-my-current-employer-that-ill-be-leaving-months-in-advance)

Comment: @JasonJ - No. My work is very IP sensitive and I have no intention of winging my PhD part-time. Also, that would close me for any other opportunities that might pop up during my doctorate.

Comment: @Lilienthal - Because I'm choosing my LOR based on people who know my investigative technical work best and not based on where they are. One from Director of Studies, one from dissertation adviser and one from my immediate technical lead from work. What's wrong with that? Technical academics don't have the same prejudice towards industry and business as those from other fields

Comment: Industry experience may be notable for grad school since it gives you "real world" experience, but you want your LOR's to come from academia since that's the world you'll be working in to get your PhD. Take it from a former engineering grad student. (I graduated)

Comment: @DLS3141 well, I do not even have three suitable people to ask from my university days (various stupid reasons) so it's not like I have very much choice here anyway.

Comment: So you completely burned all bridges with professors from your time at university but still want to return to that university to pursue a doctorate? You do realise that just about the only reason to get one is to pursue a career in academia? And that means having good relationships at the university where you're pursuing a doctorate. That's presumably also *why* they're asking for LORs in the first place. And what "opportunities" do you think you'll be getting during a doctorate? You seem to have serious misconceptions about both academia and the professional world.

Comment: @Lilienthal The question of whether the OP should be asking for a LOR or not is not at all relevant to the question of when to give notice, as that aspect is not about the workplace. If you want to debate whether a LOR from industry is worthwhile for a PhD, go discuss it at [Academia](http://academia.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @DavidK Since preserving the relationship would be critical to the OP if he needs a LOR it does factor in to the question. And I'm aware that I'm sort of abusing the comments here but this question has plenty of problems and I'm trying to figure out what the OP is after to see if his question is worth salvaging. If his plan is unrealistic there's no point in answering this question.

Comment: Ask about tuition reimbursement programs offered by your employer. There are typically multiple levels, from one-or-two courses a term and no time off  to full tuition, room, board and books with a one-term eave over absence to finish off the theses; better offers are harder to qualify for. Convince your manglement that this is in the *company's* best interest

Answer (score 0):

Risk analysis

It is not worth putting your job risk

If you cannot get into a PhD without a LOR from company then so be it

Most PhD candidates went straight from academia

If you cannot get in based on academia LOR than not likely an industry LOR will put you over the edge